# How to calculate prometheus procentage from the sums of 2 rates

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm using Grafana with prometheus datasource and I'm unable to calculate a success ration from 2 sums of rates. For example I have
`sum by (application) (rate(http_request_path_endpoint_responses{application="service1",request_path="/otp"}[5m])) / sum by (application) (rate(http_request_path_endpoint_responses{application="service1",request_path="/session"}[5m]))`

it doesn't return anything

Each of them works just fine and it produces the expected values but I can't divide them in order to get the ratio.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Have a read of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080209/prometheus-return-no-data-when-calculating-a-ratio-of-two-metrics

And see if it helps. I believe for your example, it would be `ignoring(request_path)` or `on(request_path)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as suggested by Saf using ignoring() or on() does the trick.
so `sum by (application) (rate(http_request_path_endpoint_responses{application="service1",request_path="/otp"}[5m])) / ignoring(request_path) sum by (application) (rate(http_request_path_endpoint_responses{application="service1",request_path="/session"}[5m]))` worked